# Correct Positioning of the Page Indicator View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, position

**The problem is that this page indicator View is correctly positioned on a large device but the View gets changed on a smaller screen device.If anyone of you can suggest some changes in the xml or generally so that it shows same on all types of screen it will be really helpfull. Thanks**

```
<com.rd.PageIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:piv_animationType="fill"
    app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
    app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
    app:piv_selectedColor="@color/gray_50"
    app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/gray_300"
    app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager"
    attrs:piv_padding="12dp"
    attrs:piv_radius="8dp"/>
```

**Image for the smaller screen device that is not showing the page indicator at the right place.**
[image]

**Image for larger screen where it is showing the placement of the page indicator correctly**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `layout_marginLeft` and use

```
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

to lock it at a certain distance to the right side of the screen.
I've set `16dp` but you can change that easily.

Comment: Now its just stuck on the left side its not moving an inch

Comment: sorry didn't saw that missing layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_centerInParent="true" work for me in relativeLayout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/home_slider_h"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.tiagosantos.enchantedviewpager.EnchantedViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_slider_h" />

    <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:piv_animationType="fill"
        app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
        app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
        app:piv_padding="4dp"
        app:piv_radius="5dp"
        app:piv_selectedColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager_home"
        app:tabGravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```